# Deploying JavaFX in Webstart/JNLP

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, jnlp, jar-signing

I just purchased code signing certificates from Comodo. I'm now trying to sign a Webstart/JNLP file so I can distribute it, but I get the "Application Blocked by Java Security" message.
[image]

I'm using Maven to build:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <taskdef name="jfxdeploy" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                        <taskdef name="jfxsignjar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXSignJarTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                        <jfxdeploy outdir="${project.build.directory}/jnlp"
                                   outfile="jnlp-test"
                                   embedJNLP="true">

                            <info title="JNLP Test"
                                  vendor="Foo Bar"
                                  description=""/>
                            <application name="${project.name}"
                                         mainClass="com.foo.CheckboxTableExample" />
                            <resources>
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.jar" />
                            </resources>

                            <permissions elevated="true"/>

                        </jfxdeploy>

                        <!-- Sign all the jars in the deploy directory -->
                        <jfxsignjar destdir="${project.build.directory}/jnlp"
                                    keyStore="cert.pfx"
                                    storetype="pkcs12"
                                    storePass="****"
                                    alias="myalias">
                            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/jnlp" includes="*.jar" />
                        </jfxsignjar>

                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                <version>8.0</version>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
                <scope>system</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Maven compiles fine without error, and I can see the jar was signed by looking at the SIGNATURES.BSF file in the jar. But I am flummoxed as to why I still get this error.

I have also cleared my cache/Temporary File Settings in Java to ensure it is not referencing an old version.

Can anyone shed light on this?

**EDIT:**

My JNLP output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="jnlp-test.jnlp">    
  <information>
    <title>JNLP Test</title>
    <vendor>Foo Bar</vendor>
    <description></description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="test-jnlp-1.0.jar" size="6834" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="0" height="0" main-class="com.foo.CheckboxTableExample"  name="Test JNLP" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

The output of JaNeLA clearly shows I have some errors:

```
Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase not specified.  Defaulting to file:/D:/workspace/test-jnlp/target/jnlp/
Resource 'test-jnlp-1.0.jar' declared as size '6834' but is actually '10571'.
The resource download at test-jnlp-1.0.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at test-jnlp-1.0.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the test-jnlp-1.0.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for test-jnlp-1.0.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

And finally, clearly my jar is **not** signed according to the jarsign -verify command

```
jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the jfxsigner command.

**Edit 2:**
Now what I know the jar signing did not work, I tried to do it manually using the jarsigner on the command line and got an error about the cert I was issued

```
Warning:
The signer's certificate chain is not validated.
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2016-08-03) or after any future revocation date.
```

So that's an issue I need to take to Comodo about.

Comment: 1) *"I'm using Maven to build:"*  What is the JNLP file that results from that?  Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).  2) When you use the JRE tools to check the digital signature on the Jar(s), what does it report?  Copy/paste that info. as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31844959/edit).

Comment: Ugg. I must really be blind. I can't see why the jar says its not signed. The output in maven says its signing the correct jar. And its the very last step so nothing else is messing with it.

Comment: Also be sure to fix the errors (don't worry about the warnings or optimizations yet) reported by JaNeLA.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve my issues.

First issue was that I had a Rogue Root Certificate for Comodo in Windows. That needed to be removed and the proper ones installed.

Second issue, was I needed to import the pfx file and certs into a keystore. I'm not actually sure this was necessary, but I did it in the chain of events.

Third issue was that "No -tsa" error. I assumed this was a problem with the certificate Comodo gave me and they didn't say otherwise. But through searching I found that adding -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com to the jarsigner got rid of that warning.

Fourth issue was that the jxsignjar didn't work. First it didn't report an error when the jar signing failed. Next, I needed to place the signjar before the deploy anyhow (my mistake). Finally, it doesn't allow for the -tsa option. I ended up using an ant task to sign the jar.

I used the JaNeLA tool to inspect the jnlp file. Its a cool tool but I don't think it is updated to support JavaFX. For instance, it flags an error on

```
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="0" height="0" main-class="com.foo.CheckboxTableExample"  name="Test JNLP" />
```

It wants something in the old format like

```
<application-desc main-class="com.foo.CheckboxTableExample" />
```

Thanks for your help Andrew. Now I need to figure out whether Webstart is better than an installer.